# How to get the ip range of github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com?

Tags: firewall

I have denied all outgoing traffic, but need to allow some of them in order to allow the installation of certain software packages. One of such packages resides on github and that means that the ip range of `github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com` has to be allowed, but after adding a couple of ip addresses it turns out that there are multiple ips.

**Attempt to solve the issue**

https://api.github.com/meta was found and returns the ips, but not those of AWS

**Current approach**

As a workaround I have allow outgoing connection to `52.216/16`, but that it is too open

Comment: IP filtering is quite 'old school' and absolutely not adapted... Targeting S3, take aws S3 endpoints IP at worst. Better use an artifact proxy like nexus or a proxy to filter on urls IMO

Comment: See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html if you really want to go this way, but there's quite large ranges, the 52.216.0.0 is a /15 for us-east-1 and not a /16 btw {
      "ip_prefix": "52.216.0.0/15",
      "region": "us-east-1",
      "service": "S3"
    },

Comment: Side question: outgoing from where ? internal network ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tensibai indicated that:

> See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html if you
>   really want to go this way, but there's quite large ranges, the
>   52.216.0.0 is a /15 for us-east-1 and not a /16 btw { "ip_prefix": "52.216.0.0/15", "region": "us-east-1", "service": "S3" },